# Passing list/model as parameter with @url.action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, model

Is there a way to pass list as parameter for `@url.action` or is there a better solution for this?

Pseudo code:
This doesn't pass anything, unless I define index for my model or list.

```
 @Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed", "Home", new { selectedids = /*model or list?*/ }, null)
```

I need to pass list or model to this:

```
  public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(List<int> selectedids) {

       //Code
       return View("Index");

  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is better, but I created an object with attributes for a link, then when I iterated the object I simply would link to a property.  `<a href="@model.URL">@model.Name</a>` sort of thing.

Comment: You can pass Id's through ajax ..

Comment: For delete/update, always use http post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I join them as a string and then convert that back on the server; this means selectedids would need to be a string on the server, which you would string split on comma and convert each value to `long`.

```
@Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed", "Home", new { selectedids = String.Join(",", Model.IDS) })
```